# Turn on/off vibration and sound while receiving remote notification ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, vibration, remote-notifications

I have settings in my app, in that I have a toggle button for turning **On** and **Off** the **sound** and **vibration** as well, while receiving remote notification. Below is my code for registering remote notification in `AppDelegate`

```
let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
    let pushNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(pushNotificationSettings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

For sound I referred this [Remove sound from notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167185/remove-sound-from-notification) but it does'nt seems to work.

Whatsapp having this feature, so surely it will be possibly

Can anyone please advise in this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please remove sound key-value from JSON payload.

I have just checked it. It works for me.

```
{"aps":{"alert":"Enter your message","badge":1}}
```

Comment: Thanks :-) It works. Do you have any idea about Vibration?

Comment: I was not getting vibrations when when phone is on ringing mode.

Comment: Yes, but if the vibration is turned on in the phone settings it's vibrating otherwise it's not vibrating. Is there any way to handle vibration within our app? I have seen this in Whatsapp